# Convert csv data to nested json data

Tags: python, json, loops, nested

I have a csv data as:

> dataf = pd.DataFrame{'title':['tit1', 'tit1', 'tit2' 'tit2','tit3'],
> 'context':['con1', 'con1', 'con2', 'con2', 'con3'],
> 'answers':['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4', 'text5'],
> 'question':['que1', 'que2', 'que3', 'que4', 'que5'],
> 'id':['DDA', 'SAV', 'AFS', 'ML', 'MLI']}

I wanted to convert it to nested json format as below using python:

```
[
  {
    "title": "tit1",
    "paragraph": [
      {
        "context": "con1",
        "qas": [
          {
            "answers": "text1",
            "question": "que1",
            "id": "DDA"
          },
          {
            "answers": "text2",
            "question": "que2",
            "id": "SAV"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "tit2",
    "paragraph": [
      {
        "context": "con2",
        "qas": [
          {
            "answers": "text3",
            "question": "que3",
            "id": "AFS"
          },
          {
            "answers": "text4",
            "question": "que4",
            "id": "ML"
          }

        ],
        "context": "con3",
        "qas": [
          {
            "answers": "text5",
            "question": "que5",
            "id": "MLI"
          }
        ]

      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: you example code for pandas doesn't work, wouldn't a simple dataf.tojson() solve this?

Comment: dataf.tojson() will give a bunch of data in json but not in nested format as expected

Comment: then you need to group your dataframe with groupby before you convert your data to json